# Are registration keys for Adobe CS5 or CS5.5 platform specific (Mac or PC)?

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I have the 30 day trial of CS5 Design Standard installed on my Mac.  A friend purchased CS5 Design Standard for PC, but has decided not to keep it.  They have not registered it with their key yet.  Will their key (for PC) work on my Mac version?

Comment: Is there a downside to trying it?

Comment: @soandos shouldn't be, it'll either reject or accept

Comment: @Matt, try it. It can't hurt. Feel free to post the answer to your own question when you find out. This is not a site for random tech support questions in general. You should try to solve the problem on your own first. Welcome to SuperUsuer.

Comment: @soandos what happens of the OP can't try it out? Maybe the friend is selling the key and not giving it (which precludes any chance of 'trying' a key out)?

Comment: Thanks, the 'friend' scenario was just a fictional example to explain my question better.  Looks like @digixp has looked into it, and says they're platform specific, so I'll accept that answer.  Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember from looking this up a couple of months ago is that yes, they are, though if you ask nicely enough they might transfer it, and volume licenses (ex. if you get it from a school) are cross-platform.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Adobe has it embedded in the EULA that you can transfer your license across platforms, but you'll have to call Adobe in order to do it, since the serial numbers are platform specific.